# Command to list reordered ls columns works in terminal but not through running a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I'm trying to make a script that will print information of all files in a given directory in order of owner, group, filename, then permissions separated by commas. The code I wrote works fine when ran in terminal, but when I try to run it through a script with a directory given as $1, it only prints the owner name once and nothing else. What am I overlooking?

here's the code:

```
 ls -l | awk '{print $3, ",", $4, ",", $9, ", " $1}'
```

works fine in terminal, but

```
 ls -l "$1" | awk '{print $3, ",", $4, ",", $9, ", " $1}'
```

ran from $script.sh directoryname outputs only the user name once and that's it.

Comment: Filenames are allowed to contain commas, so I'd recommend you list it _last_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
Use [`stat`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) instead

```bash
stat -c '%U,%G,%n,%A' "$1"/*
```

That puts the directory name in the output, so you might want to `cd "$1"` then use `stat ... *`

---

Another option: `find`

```bash
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%u,%g,%P,%M\n'
```

Comment: Hmm I tried this but it seems to only output the info for the directory itself, not the files within?

Comment: I missed the "all the files in a given directory" bit. I'll edit.